# Facebook Apps - Picture uploading failed from today

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, image-uploading

Error Message : OAuthException: (#100) Cannot specify user tags without a place tag

But I haven't changed any coding.
I can still upload without tags. What could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: I am still getting the same problem. Has facebook changed tagging coding? Or is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

FACEBOOK IS A NIGHTMARE. I am in production and basically the app stopped working from night to day.
Here's the workaround. Please somebody translate this into proper PHP sdk

AFTER YOU POST YOUR PHOTO and you get back the id

```
    $post_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$photo[id]."/tags/"
    . $user['id']."?access_token=".$token."&x=" . 20 ."&y=20"
     ."&method=POST";
    $response = file_get_contents($post_url);
```

Again I'd be grateful if somebody now help me in passing this using the PHP SDK

Comment: Did you find a way to fix it?

Comment: This actually works. Only now the process is in 2 steps. First you post the photo. Then you get the photo ID and you tag the photo.